# iOS Core Data - Lightweight migration for changing relationship from non-optional to optional

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data, core-data-migration

The documentation around [Core Data lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) doesn't mention whether or not marking a relationship from non-optional to optional would be covered under lightweight migration.

Is it handled by lightweight migration or will i have to write a custom migration for it? Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this change would be OK, but the only way to know for sure is to try it: Make sure you have a backup of your code. Run the existing code and add some data to your app. Now make the change to the relationship in Core Data and run the app again on the same device. If it does not crash when accessing your data, then it worked.

Comment: Also make sure to version your model before changing the relationship. That is always required for lightweight migrations.

Comment: Already tried that and it works but i am having an issue with one of my apps in market wherein i am facing failures around lightweight migration. I am not able to zero in on the issue that's why i am speculating on all fronts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that page covers this exact case. Included in the list of changes that can be inferred is:

> - A non-optional attribute becoming optional

So, if you attempt lightweight migration with only this change, it should work.

Comment: I was confused between the terminology of an attribute and a relationship. I thought the terminology is strict when we say attribute and it should not mean a relationship.

Comment: Can you please shed a little more light on this?

Comment: @jarora You asked if it would work; I explained that it does work. What part do you need more light to be shed upon?

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience i would just raise a bug related to the documentation.